# Calculate a number of all posible combinations

Tags: math, combinations, combinatorics

There are 10 variables that can have 115 possible values. These values can not repeat. How do I calculate the number of all possible combinations?

Comment: `comb(115,10)=74540394223878` according to Wolfram alfa.

Comment: So as far I remember from my college classes it's either 10^115 or 115^10. Is that correct? The number seems too big

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Thanks for your answer but I need a formula for this value, and explanation if possible

Comment: @J. Doe   John Alexiou means https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient (for case when order is not important). Your supposition about 115^10 is wrong due to `can not repeat`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not about programming but math. This needs to be on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: here is the input [in Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=comb%28115%2C10%29) which also gives you the formula in terms of factorials **`!`**.

Answer (score 1):

It is the faculty of 115 divided by the faculty of 115-10.

```
115! / (115-10)!
115 * 114 * 113 * 112 * 111 * 110 * 109 * 108 * 107 * 106
```

Because for the first of 10 variables you have a choice of 115 values, for the second one less, i.e. 114 ... and so on.